# How to combine an array into a single string value when using CSV output in jq?

Tags: json, csv, jq

I have the following `jq` command:

```
cat myFile.json | jq -r '.tickets[] | [.created_at, .id, .via.channel, .tags[]] | @csv'
```

And it outputs a line such as:

```
"2016-02-02T10:00:00Z",99999,"web","tag1","tag2","tag3","tag4"
```

I'm trying to `join` the `.tags[]` array, so that I can get:

```
"2016-02-19T13:25:55Z",99999,"web","tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4"
```

I've tried a few things, such as

```
cat myFile.json | jq -r '.tickets[] | [.created_at, .id, .via.channel, (.tags[] | join(","))] | @csv'
```

But it gives errors such as

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot iterate over string ("tag1...)
```

So, how can I join `.tags[]` in the command above so that instead of separate fields, I get a single string value (containing comma separated tag values in it)?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You need to call `join()` on the `tags` list, not the individual tags. Try with:

```
jq -r '.tickets[] | [.created_at, .id, .via.channel, (.tags | join(","))] | @csv'
```