# Using jq to concatenate multiple entries into a single string value?

Tags: json, jq

I've been experimenting for quite a while now and also researched stackoverflow and came across this question which comes closes to what I'm trying to achieve:
[How to combine an array into a single string value when using CSV output in jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45165303/how-to-combine-an-array-into-a-single-string-value-when-using-csv-output-in-jq)

My JSON output looks quite a big more complicated though:

```
"content": [
{
    "type": "paragraph",
    "content": [
        {
            "type": "inlineCard",
            "attrs": {
            "url": "https://www.myurl.com"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "text",
            "text": " "
        }
    ]
},
{
    "type": "paragraph",
    "content": [
        {
            "type": "inlineCard",
            "attrs": {
                "url": "https://www.anotherurl.com"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "text",
            "text": " "
        }
    ]
},
{
    "type": "paragraph",
    "content": [
        {
            "type": "inlineCard",
            "attrs": {
                "url": "https://www.andanotherurl.com"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "text",
            "text": " "
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I would now like to get the following result:

```
"https://www.myurl.com, https://www.anotherurl.com, https://www.andanotherurl.com"
```

I've tried the following:

```
echo $MY_JSON | jq '[ .content[].content[] | select(.type | contains("inlineCard")) | .attrs.url | join(",") ]'
```

but that tells me

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot iterate over string ("http://ww...)
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the solution myself, the trick was to end the array before sending it to the `join` function:

```
echo $MY_JSON | jq '[ .content[].content[] | select(.type | contains("inlineCard")) | .attrs.url ] | join(",")'
```